# Selenium/python 2.7 How to use if/else with find_element?

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, element

What I want is to say if element1 is displayed, click, if not check if element2 is displayed, click, etc. But my code stops when an element isnt there. If element1 is there, it clicks it, if it is not there, the code stops but I want it to keep going through each elif until it finds one, any help is appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.set_window_size(1400, 1000)
driver.get('')

elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@title='img1']")

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@title='img2']")

if elem.is_displayed():
    elem.click()
    print "true"
elif elem1.is_displayed():
    elem1.click()
    print "1true"
else:
    print "false"
```

The error is

> selenium,common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img[@title='img1']"}

Comment: What do you mean by "the code stops" - are you getting any errors? Also, is this intentional that both xpath expressions are the same? Thanks.

Comment: Not related to the answer... but I would suggest that you name your variables something more clear. I would rename `elem1` to `image1` and `elem` to `image2` or something more clear. it will make your code more readable and understandable to you and others.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that an element was not found at all. In other words, it is not not displayed, it is *not present*.

I would make a list of elements/locators (assuming you want to scale it), loop over the list and handle `NoSuchElementException` error. Exit the loop once you click an element:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

locators = [
    (By.XPATH, "//img[@title='img1']"),
    (By.XPATH, "//img[@title='img2']")
]

for by, value in locators:
    try:
        driver.find_element(by, value).click()
        break  # exit once we click an element
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass  # element is not present - okay, move on
```